# KineticJS layer index when dragging

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

So my problem seems to be that a draggable object always is drawn over other objects.

Check out my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgable/nYHrg/).

and my **code**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            canvas {
                border: 1px solid #9C9898;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.1-beta.js"></script>
        <script>
         window.onload = function() {

            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 578,
            height: 200
            });

            var cableLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();


// build cable
var cable = new Kinetic.Line({
  strokeWidth: 40,
  stroke: 'green',
  points: [{
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2
  }, {
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  }],
  draggable: true
});

// build center

var c1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
  radius: 60,
  fill: 'black',
  draggable: true,
  x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
  y: stage.getHeight() / 2
});



var c2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  radius: 60,
  fill: 'black',
  draggable: true,
});

//add everything to the layer


cableLayer.add(cable);
cableLayer.add(c1);
cableLayer.add(c2);




//add all to stage
stage.add(cableLayer);



//What to do when something is changed...

cable.on('dragmove', (function () {
  c1.setPosition([cable.getPosition().x + cable.getPoints()[0].x, cable.getPosition().y + cable.getPoints()[0].y]);
  c2.setPosition([cable.getPosition().x + cable.getPoints()[1].x, cable.getPosition().y + cable.getPoints()[1].y]);  

  cableLayer.draw();

}));

c1.on('dragstart', (function () {
  c1.getLayer().afterDraw(function () {
    cable.attrs.points[0].x = c1.getX()-cable.getX();
    cable.attrs.points[0].y = c1.getY()-cable.getY();
    cableLayer.draw();

  });
}));

c2.on('dragstart', (function () {
  c2.getLayer().afterDraw(function () {
    cable.attrs.points[1].x = c2.getX()-cable.getX();
    cable.attrs.points[1].y = c2.getY()-cable.getY();
    cableLayer.draw();
  });
}));


}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onmousedown="return false;">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, I tried to set the index using

```
 cable.on('dragmove', (function () {
  c1.setPosition([cable.getPosition().x + cable.getPoints()[0].x, cable.getPosition().y + cable.getPoints()[0].y]);
  c2.setPosition([cable.getPosition().x + cable.getPoints()[1].x, cable.getPosition().y + cable.getPoints()[1].y]);  
   c2.setIndex(1);
  c1.setIndex(1);
  cable.setIndex(2);
  cableLayer.draw();

}));
```

Doesn't seem to work? Why is this? How do I get the circles to draw over the line in all cases? Mainly the case that you drag the line.

Is there somewhere I'm setting this differently somewhere else?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nYHrg/3/

So the problem is that kineticjs (4.3.0) added a new 'drag' layer to improve dragging performance. Any time that you drag an object, it is put in the drag layer, and when you stop dragging, it is put back in it's own layer. This does not preserve your original z-index. Anytime you create a new object and you want to override this functionality you will have to set one of the attributes of the object as:

```
 "dragOnTop: false"
```

see jsfiddle for exact implementation.

Comment: How did you even know this? Thanks so much.

Comment: I read the documentation. http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php , and it's in the change-log https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log