# Composition of draggable and static layers in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to use KineticJS to build a simple strategy game. I have one Kinetic.Stage resized to fit the entire screen. On that stage I intend to have three rendering layers in general. Top most the HUD layer showing the game stats - obviously not draggable. One layer below is the "Action Layer", where the game map an all the action is to be displayed. On the bottom is a static background layer, displaying some kind of a backdrop - uninteresting in this example.
I intend to have my action layer draggable in order to scroll around the map.
The problem is, it doesn't seem to work this way, the action layer can't be dragged. I must be missing something.

I have reproduced the problem in a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/shadowfire/2v9xS/22/

Also I have found out, that adding a shape to the root of the action layer allows dragging of the layer - but only if you drag that shape, which doesn't seem to be great solution.

The corresponding code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'myCanvas',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    draggable: false,
    listening: true
}); 

var backgroundLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({draggable: false});
var actionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({draggable: true, listening: true});
var mapLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({draggable: true});
var foregroundLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({draggable: true, clearBeforeDraw: false});
var hudLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({draggable: false});

backgroundLayer.add(new Kinetic.Rect(
    {
        x:0,
        y:0,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        fill: 'grey'
    }
));

mapLayer.add(new Kinetic.Rect(
    {
        x:100,
        y:100,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        fill: 'orange',
        stroke: 'black',
        draggable: true
    }
));

foregroundLayer.add(new Kinetic.Circle(
    {
        x:200,
        y:200,
        radius: 30,
        fill: 'yellow',
        stroke: 'black',
        draggable: true
    }
));

actionLayer.add(mapLayer);
actionLayer.add(foregroundLayer);
actionLayer.add(new Kinetic.Text({text:"ActionLayer - draggable works only here", fill:'green', x:100, y:100}));

hudLayer.add(new Kinetic.Text(
    {
        fontSize: 30,
        text: 'STATUS',
        fill: 'green'
    }
));

stage.add(backgroundLayer);
stage.add(actionLayer);
stage.add(hudLayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in my opinion come from the fact that you include layer into layer. The draggable get mess up. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493567/kineticjs-layer-index-when-dragging) is a possible explanation of the bug. Plus the fact that you set the whole stage as `listening:false`. If you just remove the `listening:false` from the stage you'll see that you can drag your actionLayer by dragging on the text of this layer and only this area.

A workaround if you want only the whole layer to be draggable is to change the `mapLayer` and `foregroundLayer` into group.
I am not sure what exactly you want but on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v9xS/27/) I did set the `actionLayer` draggable and such as when you drag on the mapLayer you in fact drag the actionLayer and when you drag on the foregroundlayer you only drag this group.

> var mapLayer = new Kinetic.Group();
>
> var foregroundLayer = new Kinetic.Group({draggable:true});

If you only want to drag the whole layer whenever you drag anything in it just remove `draggable:true` in the foregroundlayer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Marked as answer for pointing out that layer in layer composition leads to this problem.
Sorry for misleading you by setting listening:false on the stage in the fiddle. I wasn't familiar with the jsfiddle versioning and posted a link to a different version - it also differens from the code I have copied to in my message above.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I couldn't get Kinetic.Layer to drag neither, even in the most basic example: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-the-stage-with-kineticjs/ I tried switching the draggable from the stage to the layer. I even thought that maybe it was because there was no height, width, x, y was specified so I added those in like this:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
  draggable: true,
  x:0,
  y:0,
  width:578,
  height:200,
  visible:true,
  listening: true
});
```

but **still** it didn't work like dragging a stage works! Really strange considering the docs say a layer has the property `draggable` http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Layer.html.

Anyways as an alternative, I would suggest adding a master Kinetic.Group to the layer that will hold all your objects, and set that master Group to `draggable: true`. Then I would add a rectangle that acts as a background to the master Group with the same width and height as the layer, this gives the group a height and width, so that you can drag the entire layer. Then you can add all other elements that belong to the Action layer to that group. Something like this:

```
var masterGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  x: actionLayer.getX(),
  y: actionLayer.getY(),
  draggable: true,
  name: "masterGroup"
});

actionLayer.add(masterGroup);

var actionBG = new Kinetic.Rect({
  width: actionLayer.getWidth(),
  height: actionLayer.getHeight(),
  draggable: true,
  name: "actionBG"
});

masterGroup.add(actionBG);
//masterGroup.add(moreActionLayerObjects);
```

The group will be draggable, and hold all objects inside that also need to be draggable.

Comment: The idea isn't bad, unfortunatelly it doesn't work either (at least not in jsfiddle - will have to investigate further).

Comment: +1 for setting up a functioning example. I marked user848039's post as answer because of the explicit hint to the problematic layer in layer composition.